# Transactions in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I need to have Transaction at package level. I have Nested Sequence Containers in my package and Want my package to rollback if any of the task fails in my Control flow. What is the best solution to accompolish this. I know how to set Transaction "Supported"/"Required" etc but Can anyone help me to figure out what could be the best settings especially when i have Nested Sequence Containers and want my Package to Run as ONE transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, setting `TransactionOption=Required` on package level and `Supported` on all tasks is all you need.